# How to vendorize gems in bundler for multiple platforms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

How to vendorize gems in bundler for multiple platforms ?

I am developing on Mac OSX but deploying on ubuntu 
a gem having native dependencies like libv8 can have a gem named

https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions/3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-10
and https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions/3.11.8.13-x86_64-linux
all versions can be seen at https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions

So on my Mac, when i run bundle pack. i want:
libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-10.gem and libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-linux.gem
likewise upgrading and removing a gem must remove and add other platform's gems as well

Right now on Mac it only adds libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-darwin-10.gem

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old issue, but today I still encountered the same problem, below command fix this:

```sh
bundle config specific_platform true
bundle lock --add-platform universal-darwin
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle package --all-platforms
```

Quick Test:

```sh
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
bundle config specific_platform true
bundle init
bundle lock --add-platform universal-darwin
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux
bundle add google-protobuf
bundle cache --all-platforms
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this gem https://rubygems.org/gems/libv8/versions/3.11.8.13-x86_64-linux in vendor/cache folder in your app.I do not think that you frequently update this gem on this is quite a normal solution. I also encountered this problem and found no other solution.